# Java detect CTRL+X key combination on a jtree

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, jtree

I need an example how to add a keyboard handler that detect when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> pressed on a `JTree`.

I were do this before with menu shortcut keys but with no success.

Comment: Although these suggestions will work, they really deserve a -1. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings, not KeyListeners. See: download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/…. Solutions should promote standard Swing design concepts. Using KeyListeners is used on older AWT applications which don't support key bindings.

Comment: See [camickr's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971832/1048186) answer for the working link to the Key Bindings tutorial.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add KeyListeners to any component (f)

```
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("woot!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use Toolkit.getMenuShortcutKeyMask() instead of hard-coding CTRL_MASK.  Not all platforms use Ctrl as the modifier for commands.

Comment: Key Bindings are the approach used by all Swing components.

Comment: `InputEvent.CTRL_MASK` is deprecated-ish, the extended modifiers (e.g. `InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK`) are recommended for use now.  Annoying but true.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#CTRL_MASK

Comment: `if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("woot!");
                }
            }`
Would treat "Alt+CTRL+C" = "CTRL+C". The proposed sulution actually can't distinguish from any multiple modifiers. Use rather `@Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) && ((e.getModifiers() | KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) == KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)) {
                    System.out.println("woot!");
                }
            }`

Comment: For some reason, in my testing Ctl-A shows up with KeyCode 0 and KeyChar 1. Similarly, Ctl-N shows up with KeyChar 14. (The number of the letter in the alphabet.)  Don't know if this is documented somewhere.

Comment: how about if i press CTRL + ALT + A ?

Answer (score 13):

Use KeyListener for example :

```
jTree1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ctrl + c");

            } else if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ctrl + x");

            } else if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ctrl + v");

            }
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Key Bindings are the approach used by all Swing cvomponents.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
    initComponents();
      KeyboardFocusManager ky=KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();

    ky.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

             if (e.getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                System.out.println("Dhanushka Tharindu");
            }
             return  true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should also provide an explanation of how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

But menu shortcut accelerators are the way to do this normally: `myMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"));`

Comment: System reserved Key Combinations seems conflict Accelerator. i did it but its not work. any chance to add a keyboard handler to detect?

Comment: yes you can add a keylistener to the control, implement the onKeyPress() and check for the modifiers of the keyevent. I did it to detect a mousewhell + ctrl, but it should work as well in your case.