# How to use KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm writing small graphics editor and I want catch event when I press Ctrl+A

I use such code (this is test version):

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Press");
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_A :
            System.out.println("A");
            break;
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to catch Ctrl+a

I tryed something like this

```
    case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL+KeyEvent.VK_A :
        System.out.println("A+CTRL");
        break;
```

but this code `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL+KeyEvent.VK_A` returns int and maybe another key combination returns the same number

So can someone can help me

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970765/java-detect-ctrlx-key-combination-on-a-jtree

Comment: And choose [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: I strongly second @trashgod's recommendation. This is not a place for a KeyListener but rather for key bindings.

Comment: See also [*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isControlDown()` method:

```
switch (e.getKeyCode())
{
        case KeyEvent.VK_A :
            if(e.isControlDown())
               System.out.println("A and Ctrl are pressed.");
            else
                System.out.println("Only A is pressed");
            break;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.....

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                System.out.println("woot!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `isControlDown` method on `KeyEvent`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown%28%29