# how to implement ctrl+backspace and ctrl+delete for a text edior in swt

Tags: java, swt, text-editor, e4, listeners

I have created an SWT text editor and also have implemented the cut, copy and paste features but now I need to implement <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, to delete the preceding word, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, to delete the proceeding word.

The code which copied text

```
private class Copy implements SelectionListener{
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {  
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {     
                copySelectedMessages();
            }

            private void copySelectedMessages(){
                //StringBuffer stringCopied =new StringBuffer();

                String textData = editor.getSelectionText();
                //TextTransfer textTransfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();

                System.out.println("you hv selected"+textData);

                //Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(Display.getDefault());
                TextTransfer transfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();      
                clipboard.setContents(new Object[] { textData }, new TextTransfer[] { transfer });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code for the editor

```
editor = new StyledText( this, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL );
editor.setLayoutData( new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH) );
editor.setFont( new Font(Display.getDefault(),"Cambria", 10, SWT.NORMAL) );
```

The listener

```
proceeding.addSelectionListener(new proceed());

private class proceed implements SelectionListener{
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {      
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {      
                // Code to check for CTRL + backspace and CTRL + delete
            }
    });
}
```

So now how can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>DELETE</kbd>functionality can be implemented in SWT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659801/java-check-if-control-key-is-being-pressed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970765/java-detect-ctrlx-key-combination-on-a-jtree

Comment: I need the logic to how to delete the preeceeding word and proceeding word when the listener is called.I hv the code to call the listener but not getting the logic

Comment: Well, where is your listener ?

Comment: It is updated in the question you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addSelectionListener()` is the wrong method to use here; use `addKeyListener()` and then a `KeyAdapter` to process the events.

java2s has an example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.eclipse.swt.custom/StyledTextaddKeyListenerKeyListenerkey.htm

or here for a more complete one: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Asimpleeditor.htm

Your code to implement "copy to clipboard" is not necessary since `StyledText` already implements this. Just call the `copy()` method. The second example shows how to install a global listener for <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> via a menu item.

As for how to delete the next or previous word, call `st.invokeAction()` with `ST.DELETE_WORD_NEXT` or `ST.DELETE_WORD_PREVIOUS` (`org.eclipse.swt.custom.ST`).

By default, those actions are bound to <kbd>Ctrl+BackSpace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Delete</kbd>. But again, those keys only trigger the action when the widget has the focus. If you want to enable them no matter which widget in the window has the focus, then create a menu item.

Comment: can you implement the invokeAction() method